# Unity3d add time on countdown timer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I want to add 10 second on timer, when Player hits PowerUp.
I have timer script, added on Canvas.

So I tried to add time in PowerUp script (I used `PlayerPrefs.SetInt`), but `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` in timer script is always true, so immediately add some time on my counter..

This is timer.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text textTime;
    public float second = 0;
    private int minutes = 1;
    public int second2 = 0;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {         
        textTime.text = minutes + ":" + second2;
        second -= Time.deltaTime;
        second2 = (int)second;

        if (second < 1)
        {
            minutes--;
            second += 60f;    
        }
        if (minutes == 0 && second2 == 1)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gameover", 0);
            Application.LoadLevel("gameover");
        }
       if ((PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timer")) == 1)
       {            
          second2 += 10;   
       }
    }
 }
```

And this is PowerUp script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start () {

    }

    Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timers", 1);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted some rudimentary debugging? Try printing the `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timer")` value to the console as well as `minutes` and `second2`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippets provided, you never change the `PlayerPrefs` "timer" to anything but "1" so you always end up adding +10 to `second2`.

Perhaps you meant to change it in the following IF statement:

```
if (minutes == 0 && second2 == 1)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gameover", 0);
    Application.LoadLevel("gameover");
}
```

Change it to:

```
if (minutes == 0 && second2 == 1)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("timer", 0);
    Application.LoadLevel("gameover");
}
```